# Apex multiple y-axis Mixed chart not displaying properly

Tags: javascript, apexcharts

The below-mentioned script shows the output as shown in the attached picture.
The data are displayed properly but except for the last one. In my data, you can see the data of 17th Jan is showing only two columns which are supposed to show 3 columns. On the other hand, if I use the zoom out tool, It displays all the data properly.

I need help to display the data normally without zoom out. I think it might have an issue with the CSS of the graph

**I am fetching the data from a JSON file using for each loop

```
 <script>
          var options = {
                   series: [{
                   name: 'T.Ticket Closed',
                   type: 'column',
                   data: [<?php     
                            foreach ($json as $key => $value) {
                            echo $value["ttc_closed"] . ", ";
                            }
                            ?>]
                 }, {
                   name: 'T.Ticket Open',
                   type: 'column',
                   data: [<?php     
                            foreach ($json as $key => $value) {
                            echo $value["ttc_open"] . ", ";
                            }
                            ?>]
                 }, {
                   name: 'Pending 24H Plus',
                   type: 'column',
                   data: [<?php     
                            foreach ($json as $key => $value) {
                            echo $value["24p"] . ", ";
                            }
                            ?>]
                 },
                {
                   name: 'T.Ticket Solved Ratio',
                   type: 'line',
                   data: [<?php     
                            foreach ($json as $key => $value) {
                            echo $value["ttc_solve_r"] . ", ";
                            }
                            ?>]
                 }],
                   chart: {
                   height: 350,
                   type: 'line',
                   stacked: false
                 },
                 dataLabels: {
                   enabled: true
                   
                 },
                 stroke: {
                   width: [1, 1, 1, 4]
                 },
                 title: {
                   text: '',
                   align: 'left',
                   offsetX: 110
                 },
                 xaxis: {
                  type: 'datetime',
                   categories: [<?php   
            foreach ($json as $key => $value) {
            echo date("'d F Y' ",strtotime($value["report_date"])). ", ";
            }
            ?>],
                 },
                 yaxis: [
                   {
                     axisTicks: {
                       show: true,
                     },
                     axisBorder: {
                       show: true,
                       color: '#008FFB'
                     },
                     labels: {
                       style: {
                         colors: '#008FFB',
                       }
                     },
                     title: {
                       text: "",
                       style: {
                         color: '#008FFB',
                       }
                     },
                     tooltip: {
                       enabled: true
                     }
                   },
                   {
                     seriesName: '',
                     opposite: true,
                     axisTicks: {
                       show: true,
                     },
                     axisBorder: {
                       show: true,
                       color: '#00E396'
                     },
                     labels: {
                       style: {
                         colors: '#00E396',
                       }
                     },
                     title: {
                       text: "",
                       style: {
                         color: '#00E396',
                       }
                     },
                   },
                   {
                     seriesName: '',
                     opposite: true,
                     axisTicks: {
                       show: true,
                     },
                     axisBorder: {
                       show: true,
                       color: '#FEB019'
                     },
                     labels: {
                       style: {
                         colors: '#FEB019',
                       },
                     },
                     title: {
                       text: "",
                       style: {
                         color: '#FEB019',
                       }
                     }
                   },
                   {
                     seriesName: '',
                     opposite: true,
                     axisTicks: {
                       show: true,
                     },
                     axisBorder: {
                       show: true,
                       color: '#FB0021'
                     },
                     labels: {
                       style: {
                         colors: '#FB0021',
                       },
                     },
                     title: {
                       text: "",
                       style: {
                         color: '#FB0021',
                       }
                     }
                   },
                 ],
                 tooltip: {
                   fixed: {
                     enabled: true,
                     position: 'topLeft', // topRight, topLeft, bottomRight, bottomLeft
                     offsetY: 30,
                     offsetX: 60
                   },
                 },
                 legend: {
                   horizontalAlign: 'left',
                   offsetX: 40
                 }
                 };
                
                
                
                //TT ressolution
                
                 var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#tt_resolution"), options);
                 chart.render();
</script>
```

[image: my graph result]

Comment: Try once by adding  width: "100%", or use a responsive property of the chart sonthing like responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 1000,
      options: {
        plotOptions: {
          bar: {
            horizontal: false
          }
        },
        legend: {
          position: "bottom"
        }
      }
    }
  ]

Comment: still not working

Comment: Try adding grid: { padding: { right: 30 } }

Comment: This is working for me. I've add right and left padding both
grid: { 
       padding: { 
                right: 30,
                left: 30 
        } 
  },